# ¿Cómo puedo comparar cadenas de carácteres pedidas al usuario y guardándolas con fgets en C?

Tags: c, string

Uso GNU/Linux y compilo con gcc.

El programa compila bien, pero no entra en el if, incluso si la cadena de carácteres introducida en la variable sexo es: "masculino".

Código:

```
/* Hacer un programa que pida nombre, sexo y edad al usuario
y que imprima su nombre sólo si éste es de sexo masculino y mayor de edad. */
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
int main()
{
   char nombre[50],sexo[20];
   int edad;
   printf("Introduzca su nombre: ");fgets(nombre,50,stdin);
   printf("Introduzca su sexo: ");fgets(sexo,20,stdin);
   printf("Introduzca su edad: ");scanf("%i",&edad);
   printf("Verificando los datos ingresados...\n");
   sleep(2);
   if(strcmp(sexo,"masculino") == 0)
      {
         if(edad > 100)
         {
            printf("Edad no válida.\n");
         }
         else if(edad > 18)
         {
            printf("Su nombre es: %s",nombre);
         }
         else
         {
            printf("Lo siento, no es mayor de edad.\n");
         }
      }
      else
      {
         printf("Lo siento, no es de sexo masculino.\n");
      }
      return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu problema es que estás intentando utilizar strcmp, que es una función para strings, utilizando una cadena de caracteres normal (no string). es decir, la función strcmp funciona con strings, con lo que necesita que las cadenas de caracteres acaben en \0 (ya que para C una cadena de caracteres es un string si el último caracter es \0).

Para hacer que tu variable "sexo" sea un string, puedes ponerle el \0 al final manualmente, pero es mejor que justo después del fgets de sexo hagas:

```
sscanf(sexo,"%s",sexo);
```

De esta manera, sscanf transforma la cadena de caracteres a string (quitándole el \n del final y poniéndole un \0). He probado tu código con esto y parece que funciona bien.

Aparte, te recomendaría que al recoger cualquier tipo de variable de teclado lo hicieras utilizando fgets y sscanf, ya que scanf puede dar problemas, sobre todo con los saltos de línea. Así, por ejemplo para la variable edad, sería mejor hacer:

```
printf("Introduzca su edad: ");fgets(str,20,stdin);sscanf(str,"%i",&edad);
```

Siendo str un char[20] auxiliar para las lecturas

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que `fgets` está cargando el salto de línea en la variable `sexo` y así es como aparece [documentado](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/):

> A newline character makes fgets stop reading, but it is considered a valid character by the function and included in the string copied to str.

Es decir:

> El caracter de nueva línea hace que fgets deje de leer, sin embargo es considerado un caracter válido por la función y, por tanto, se incluye en el texto copiado en str.

Te toca eliminar el salto de línea de forma manual:

```
fgets(sexo,20,stdin);
strtok(sexo,"\n");
```

o, dado que el sexo no va a tener nunca espacios, usar `scanf`:

```
scanf("%s",sexo);
```