# Se llena el buffer Programa en C

Tags: c

tengo un problema con un programa que hace registro de nombres y datos como fecha de nacimiento y apellidos. En el primer registro cuando pido ingresar el nombre inmediatamente se llena el espacio en el arreglo sin teclear nada y me envia a ingresar los demas datos sin problema. Ya use fflush(stdin) pero no hace nada en esa sección. Quisiera saber si me pudieran orientar en solucionar este problema.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  struct persona{
   char nombre[20];
   char amaterno[20];
   char apaterno[20];
   //int anacimiento;
   int anacimiento;
   int mnacimiento;
   int dnacimiento;
   int id;
   }personas[6];
   int numero=1;
   int imprimir=1;
  int menu=0;
   int menu2=0;
   int menu3=0;
   char prueba;
int optionmenu;

fflush(stdin);
    do{
        menuprincipal:
    printf("\nBienvenido\n");
    printf("Ingrese una opcion:\n");
    printf("1.Registro y Consulta\n");
    printf("2.Salir\n");
        scanf("%d",&optionmenu);
if(optionmenu==1){

   do{
  numero++;
  printf("Ingrese su nombre\n");
  fflush(stdin);
  fgets(personas[numero].nombre,20,stdin);

   if(numero==3){

  fflush(stdin);
  fgets(personas[numero].nombre,20,stdin);
   }
   if(numero==4){

  fflush(stdin);
  fgets(personas[numero].nombre,20,stdin);
   }
  if(numero==5){

  fflush(stdin);
  fgets(personas[numero].nombre,20,stdin);
   }
  printf("Ingrese su apellido paterno\n");
   fflush(stdin);
  fgets(personas[numero].apaterno,20,stdin);
  printf("Ingrese su apellido materno\n");
  fgets(personas[numero].amaterno,20,stdin);

 do{
  printf("Ingrese su año de nacimiento\n");
  scanf("%i", &menu);
 if(menu>=1900 && menu <= 2018) {
     if(menu>=1900 && menu <=2000){
       menu= menu-1900;
      personas[numero].anacimiento= menu;
     }
     if(menu>=2000 && menu <=2100){
       menu= menu-2000;
      personas[numero].anacimiento= menu;
     }
      break;
    }
  } while(1);


 do{
  printf("Ingrese su mes de nacimiento\n");
  scanf("%i", &menu2);
 if(menu2>=1 && menu2 <= 12) {
      personas[numero].mnacimiento= menu2;
      break;
    }
  } while(1);

 do{
  printf("Ingrese su dia de nacimiento\n");
  scanf("%i", &menu3);
 if(menu3>=1 && menu3 <= 31) {
      personas[numero].dnacimiento= menu3;
      break;
    }
  } while(1);


  personas[numero].id=numero;

   }while(numero<=4);



do{
  imprimir++;
  printf("%.2s",personas[imprimir].nombre);
  printf("%.2s",personas[imprimir].apaterno);
  printf("%.2s",personas[imprimir].amaterno);
  printf("%.2i",personas[imprimir].anacimiento);
  printf("%.2i",personas[imprimir].mnacimiento);
  printf("%.2i",personas[imprimir].dnacimiento);
   printf("%.i",personas[imprimir].id);
printf("\n");


 //printf("\nUsuario registrado: %s",personas[imprimir].nombre);



}while(imprimir<=4);

}
    if(optionmenu>2){
        printf("\nFavor de ingresar un numero valido\n");
    }
    if(optionmenu==2){
        printf("Salida");
    }
}while(optionmenu !=2);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Esto se debe al retorno de carro que queda sin leer tras el scanf() y que es encontrado por el fgets(). Ya ha sido preguntado de muchas formas diferentes en este sitio, por ejemplo [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/214823/duda-escanear-caracter-c) , [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/235893/problema-al-ingresar-caracteres-con-funcion-fgets) o [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/173557/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-comparar-cadenas-de-car%C3%A1cteres-pedidas-al-usuario-y-guard%C3%A1ndolas-con). Por cierto que `fflush()` no ayuda, pues es solo para flujos de salida.

Answer (score 1):

Una solución sería usar fflush() anter de cada fgets() para borrar el buffer y que no haya retorno de carro, pero si bien esto soluciona una parte del problema, fgets() no solo debuelve el string, sino tambien al final un retorno de carro. Por lo tando yo te recomendaría usar una función para leer string como la siguiente.

```
void leer_string(char* s, int max)
{
    // Limpiar buffer
    fflush(stdin);

    // Obtener string
    fgets(s, 20, stdin);

    // Eliminar salto de línea al final
    while(*s != 0)
    {
        if(*s == '\n')
        {
            *s = '\0';
            return;
        }
        s++;
    }
}
```

Entonces reemplazarias, una código como el siguiente:

```
fflush(stdin);
fgets(personas[numero].nombre,20,stdin);
```

A un código como:

```
leer_string(personas[numero].nombre, 20);
```

En el caso de cuando lees el **optionmenu** deberías hacer tambien un fflush()

```
fflush(stdin);// fflush() aquí
scanf("%d", &optionmenu);
```

Por otra parte, en el código escribís lo siguiente:

```
do
{
    numero++;
    printf("Ingrese su nombre\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(personas[numero].nombre,20,stdin);

    if(numero==3)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(personas[numero].nombre,20,stdin);
    }
    if(numero==4)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(personas[numero].nombre,20,stdin);
    }
    if(numero==5)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(personas[numero].nombre,20,stdin);
    }
    printf("Ingrese su apellido paterno\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(personas[numero].apaterno,20,stdin);
    printf("Ingrese su apellido materno\n");
    fgets(personas[numero].amaterno,20,stdin);

    // .
    // .
    // .
```

Si prestás atención a esos **if** te darás cuenta que son innecesarios, ya que estas siempre leyendo un string para "personas[numero].nombre" ya que lo haces al inicios de los **if** por lo tanto al ser el mismo código sería innecesarios esos **if**

Comment: ¿ `fflush( )` en un *stream* de entrada ? ¿ En que documento dice que eso es siquiera correcto ?

Comment: @Trauma Puedes leer éste artículo http://www.carlospes.com/curso_de_lenguaje_c/01_11_la_funcion_fflush.php
Y si haces pruebas, lo puedes comprobar.

Comment: Prefiero esta otra: [For input streams (and for update streams on which the last operation was input), the behavior is undefined.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fflush). No se ... me fio mas de un sitio de referencia, que de un *blog* cualquiera.

Comment: @Trauma No sólo lo dice un blog, basta probarlo, compilando el código, y se puede comprobar.

Comment: ¿ Tan difícil es decir `este comportamiento no es estandard, sino que puede variar según el sistema operativo: en POSIX ..., en Windows ..., en otros presenta un comportamiento indeterminado` ?

Comment: Cualquiera que lea tu respuesta, se quedará con la idea de que lo que dices sobre `fflush( )` es **corrrecto** y **universal**, cuando **no es así**.

Comment: @Trauma La razón por la que no especifiqué ese comportamiento indeterminado, es que desconicía ese detalle, pero mira, he ... una cosa nueva que hemos aprendido

Answer (score 1):

Yo por lo regular uso la siguiente función en la cual me apoyo de la función **fgets()** para dicho uso.

```
//Funcion que facilita la entrada de caracteres por el teclado, y devuelve la cantidad de caracteres
int getstring(char * str, int max_len, FILE * src)
{
    if(str == NULL || src == NULL){
        return 0;
    }


    fgets(str, max_len, src);

    int size = strlen(str) ;

    if(str[size - 1] != '\n'){
        int c;
        while((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n');
    }else{
        str[size - 1] = '\0';
    }

    return size;
}
```

Y aquí un ejemplo de como la utilizo:

```
//Funcion que facilita la entrada de caracteres por el teclado, y devuelve la cantidad de caracteres
int getstring(char * str, int max_len, FILE * src)
{
    if(str == NULL || src == NULL){
        return 0;
    }


    fgets(str, max_len, src);

    int size = strlen(str) ;

    if(str[size - 1] != '\n'){
        int c;
        while((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n');
    }else{
        str[size - 1] = '\0';
    }

    return size;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char nombre[10];
    int size = 0;

    printf("Digita un nombre: ");
    size = getstring(nombre, 10, stdin);

    printf("Nombre: %s (%d)\n", nombre, size);

    printf("Digita un nombre: ");
    size = getstring(nombre, 10, stdin);

    printf("Nombre: %s (%d)\n", nombre, size);


    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Esto no resuelve el problema del usuario, pues no está en cómo lee la cadena, sino en que antes de pedir una cadena ha usado `scanf()`, el cual ha dejado en el buffer un retorno de carro.  Tu código no presenta ese problema al no usar `scanf()`